# Powershell Get-ADGroupMember -ne to a group

Tags: powershell, scripting

Im looking to run a script that will be run on MOST of our users, minus about 25 exceptions.

The plan was to run the script on everyone that WASNT in a group that i made, which would have these 25 users. However, I cant figure out how to run a Get-ADGroupMember that targets everyone except that group.

I tried something like:
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -ne 'GPO TEST' 
but that obviously doesnt work.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find users that are not a member of a group:

```
$groupDN = (Get-ADGroup <groupname> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName)
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!memberOf=$groupDN)"
```

Comment: this worked. I added a " | select-object sAMAccountName" to the end. this should work perfectly. thanks so much

Comment: If you want sAMAccountName strings rather than output objects, don't forget to write `Select-Object -ExpandProperty sAMAccountName` instead of just `Select-Object sAMAccountName`.